# Is it possible build image from Android things's source code

Tags: build, android-things

My company develop some app on Android things past years.
I know Google alread had give up the project.
But my boss want to try if it possilbe to build the image from the source code, make our product lives more years.

Search on google, it seems have Android things's repo on
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest/+/refs/heads/android-o-mr1-iot-release-1.0.14

I try

> repo init

, and

> repo sync

it success, good.

but after I type

> lunch

I get some error like

```
pt@pt-VirtualBox:~/IOT_1.0.14$ lunch

You're building on Linux

Lunch menu... pick a combo:
Failed to find deps of android/soong/cmd/soong_ui: Error parsing directory "/home/pt/IOT_1.0.14/external/golang-protobuf/proto": open /home/pt/IOT_1.0.14/external/golang-protobuf/proto: no such file or directory

Which would you like? [aosp_arm-eng] 
Failed to find deps of android/soong/cmd/soong_ui: Error parsing directory "/home/pt/IOT_1.0.14/external/golang-protobuf/proto": open /home/pt/IOT_1.0.14/external/golang-protobuf/proto: no such file or directory
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wOECc.png)

I git clone the missing direct protobuf via

> git clone
> https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/golang-protobuf/

I try lunch again, and get the error

```
pt@pt-VirtualBox:~/IOT_1.0.14$ lunch

You're building on Linux

Lunch menu... pick a combo:
Failed to compile android/soong/cmd/soong_ui: "/home/pt/IOT_1.0.14/prebuilts/go/linux-x86/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/compile -o /home/pt/IOT_1.0.14/out/.soong_ui_intermediates/github.com-golang-protobuf-proto/github.com/golang/protobuf/proto.a -p github.com/golang/protobuf/proto -complete -pack -nolocalimports -c 6 -trimpath /home/pt/IOT_1.0.14 /home/pt/IOT_1.0.14/external/golang-protobuf/proto/checkinit.go /home/pt/IOT_1.0.14/external/golang-protobuf/proto/decode.go /home/pt/IOT_1.0.14/external/golang-protobuf/proto/decode_gen.go /home/pt/IOT_1.0.14/external/golang-protobuf/proto/doc.go /home/pt/IOT_1.0.14/external/golang-protobuf/proto/encode.go /home/pt/IOT_1.0.14/external/golang-protobuf/proto/encode_gen.go /home/pt/IOT_1.0.14/external/golang-protobuf/proto/equal.go /home/pt/IOT_1.0.14/external/golang-protobuf/proto/extension.go /home/pt/IOT_1.0.14/external/golang-protobuf/proto/merge.go /home/pt/IOT_1.0.14/external/golang-protobuf/proto/messageset.go /home/pt/IOT_1.0.14/external/golang-protobuf/proto/proto.go /home/pt/IOT_1.0.14/external/golang-protobuf/proto/proto_methods.go /home/pt/IOT_1.0.14/external/golang-protobuf/proto/reset.go /home/pt/IOT_1.0.14/external/golang-protobuf/proto/size.go /home/pt/IOT_1.0.14/external/golang-protobuf/proto/size_gen.go /home/pt/IOT_1.0.14/external/golang-protobuf/proto/wrappers.go": exit status 2
     1. /home/pt/IOT_1.0.14/external/golang-protobuf/proto/checkinit.go:8:2:
     2. can't
     3. find
     4. import:
     5. "google.golang.org/protobuf/internal/errors"

Which would you like? [aosp_arm-eng] 
Failed to compile android/soong/cmd/soong_ui: "/home/pt/IOT_1.0.14/prebuilts/go/linux-x86/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/compile -o /home/pt/IOT_1.0.14/out/.soong_ui_intermediates/github.com-golang-protobuf-proto/github.com/golang/protobuf/proto.a -p github.com/golang/protobuf/proto -complete -pack -nolocalimports -c 6 -trimpath /home/pt/IOT_1.0.14 /home/pt/IOT_1.0.14/external/golang-protobuf/proto/checkinit.go /home/pt/IOT_1.0.14/external/golang-protobuf/proto/decode.go /home/pt/IOT_1.0.14/external/golang-protobuf/proto/decode_gen.go /home/pt/IOT_1.0.14/external/golang-protobuf/proto/doc.go /home/pt/IOT_1.0.14/external/golang-protobuf/proto/encode.go /home/pt/IOT_1.0.14/external/golang-protobuf/proto/encode_gen.go /home/pt/IOT_1.0.14/external/golang-protobuf/proto/equal.go /home/pt/IOT_1.0.14/external/golang-protobuf/proto/extension.go /home/pt/IOT_1.0.14/external/golang-protobuf/proto/merge.go /home/pt/IOT_1.0.14/external/golang-protobuf/proto/messageset.go /home/pt/IOT_1.0.14/external/golang-protobuf/proto/proto.go /home/pt/IOT_1.0.14/external/golang-protobuf/proto/proto_methods.go /home/pt/IOT_1.0.14/external/golang-protobuf/proto/reset.go /home/pt/IOT_1.0.14/external/golang-protobuf/proto/size.go /home/pt/IOT_1.0.14/external/golang-protobuf/proto/size_gen.go /home/pt/IOT_1.0.14/external/golang-protobuf/proto/wrappers.go": exit status 2
```

I read some tutorial about go language.
But I have no idea how to fix it.
It seems like a path problem.

thx, if any one can help.